# What would be a way to parse a string into series of escaped hex characters?

Tags: javascript, string

My goal is to handle some incoming string that represents a series of hex byte values and output escaped hex values.
I also have the freedom to format the string as I please (add spaces, split into chunks etc).

Example(updated):

```
var input = "FF655050"; 
var output = "\xFF\x65\x50\x50"; 
console.log(output); //ÿePP
```

I've had no success with string manipulation (append, replace) and I'm not really sure of my options here. I really want to avoid a gigantic switch case.

Edit: sorry for not specifying the output correctly. I want the actual escaped character(in escaped form), not the string representation.

Comment: Have a look into regular expressions and groups

Comment: So what you want is simply adding `\x` once before every 2 chars?

Comment: Do you want the *literal* string `"\xFF\x04\xCA\x7B"` or do you want each of those bytes converted into their respective characters?

Comment: As I've mentioned in my other comment, I want to convert the bytes into their respective character (but keep it in escaped form to pass further).

Comment: You want it escaped and unescaped at the same time? Do you mean to say that you want two different outputs?

Comment: I need the output escaped. The only reason I mentioned otherwise was to visualize the result, but I guess I just created confusion, sorry. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using a loop:**

```js
var input = "FF655050";
var output = "";
for (var i = 1; i < input.length; i+=2) {
  output += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(input[i-1] + input[i], 16));
}
alert(output)
```

**Or using regular expressions:**

```js
var input = "FF655050";
var output = input.replace(/.{0,2}/g, function(x){ return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(x, 16)) });
alert(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets the corresponding character. However I'd still like to know if I could get the character as the hex escape. Mainly because i need to output exactly 1 byte of data for each input character pair ("FF") which I'm not sure is guaranteed if I simply pass a literal. Plus I think it might create issues with different types of encoding (the bytes get passed on to a printer).

Comment: @Gerty - JavaScript always stores strings internally the same way.  It doesn't matter how you code it.  `"\x65" === "\u0065" === String.fromCharCode(101) === "e"`.  JavaScript strings are stored internally with 16 bits per character.  If the bytes are important, best send bytes, and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each set of two and prepend "\x" to it

```js
var input = "FF04CA7B";
var i = 0;
var output = "";
while( i < input.length ){
 output += "\\x" + input[i];
 if(i+1<input.length)output+=input[i+1];
 i+=2;
}
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop incremented by two should do the trick.

```
var input = "FF04CA7B";
var output = "";
for (var i=1; i<input.length; i+=2) {
  output += '\\x'+input[i-1]+input[i];
}
```